# Why should the mass of one object never be 100 times more than another?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physx

I've read in a lot of places that having two objects colliding with each other where the mass of one is over 100 times greater than that of the other will cause issues with the physics of the collision. However when I tested it myself I found no real issue with what I was trying to do.

Essentially, I'm hoping that someone can elaborate on why it is a bad thing to have the masses so wildly different between two colliding objects, as currently I haven't seen any reasoning behind why not to do it, just lots of high rep people saying don't do it.

Comment: If the physics engine decides to resolve a problem (bug object overlaps car object) by moving the objects until they no longer intersect, then a fast moving car hitting a small and stationary bug might get quite a shock.  If the numbers become extreme (10,000* instead of 100*) then floating point rounding errors are likely to become drastic also because ((bug mass + car mass)  - car mass) will not be equal to bug mass.

Comment: Ahh this is more along the lines of what I was expecting. Do you have any suggestions of what I should do in cases where collisions of such large differences in mass must occur?

Comment: Try the system you have now and test it aggressively.  If it seems OK run with it.  If it doesn't because you hit these problems you are into "special case" territory and it depends very much on what end result you are aiming for.  There probably isn't a silver bullet.  edit: don't just not do it though - if it's want you want solve it!  Otherwise nothing new will ever happen!

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one with the information you have given.

Have you ever collided with a bug while driving?  Was there some catastrophe, when it happened?

If we are placing value judgements on physical phenomenon, then it would probably be "bad" from the bug's point of view.

Comment: So what you're saying is there's no issue with inaccurate collisions, it's just not worth having objects with the collision impact of a bug floating around your scene?

Comment: From a classical standpoint, the collision just seems like it would have a negligible effect on the larger object.  The larger object is going to win, big time.  I cannot speak to the quantum level, as I only have a cursory knowledge of it.  If you created a game where you were hitting tiny bugs with a vehicle, then from the vehicle perspective, the actual collision would be all you cared about.  The vehicle would not be affected unless the accumulated mass from the bug sticking to it affected it, and that would probably take a lot of bugs.

Comment: (This has no connection at all with anything - the issue is how PhysX works.)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's still reading this old question, there are two salient points

1) The simplest, factual, way to explain it is, it's very hard for PhysX to deal with this.  It's a game physics system that works at staggering speed, so it relies on certain reasonable domains.

{So, note that - quite simply - you can make similar comments such as **"Don't try to have 500+ objects colliding at once"** or **"Don't try to have things moving extremely slowly"**.  It's "only human", PhysX is mind-boggling but only so much is possible for the math and the solvers.}

2) Importantly, **this is something of an old wives' tale** .... for 2018, it's largely not true any more.

## It's simple not true any more:

Funnily enough, here's an outstanding answer which shows it working perfectly, in a complex situation!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961508/294884

[image]

Click to watch the anime ..

There is really no problem at all with "100x" differentials these days (2018+).  You could possibly say "1000x" is starting to get a bit flakey.  And "10,000x" might cause trouble.